# Stop user action for qt Separator

Tags: c++, qt

I have some dockwidgets and there are separators around them.
But for some reason, I hope to lock all the dockwidgets' size for a while.
How could I stop the user interaction for those Seaprators?

Comment: What do you mean by `QSeparator`? Is it something non-standard because I don't see such class in Qt?

Comment: Sorry, just a typo, I mean the separators, the line you can drag to change the size of the qdockwidgets

Comment: I think he meant QSplitter

Comment: Which separators? `QSplitter`? In that case you may restore (a previously saved) state with `restoreState()` in result of `splitterMoved` signal. Also a zero `handleWidth` will temporary prevent users to change it. Little bit more prolix (maybe) but more _professional_ approach is to set fixed size for widgets (not separators). `QSplitter` won't resize fixed size widgets (`width` or `height` according to splitter's `Orientation`). Also `setStretchFactor(index, 0)` may work (for each widget) but here I'm guessing (never tried).